# Change cell in csv with python

Tags: python, csv, cell

How do you change a value in a certain cell using Python 2.7? Is creating a database the best way to go?
(changed '1 dozen' to 12 twice - each time '1 dozen' is found it is replaced with 12)

Input:

```
['item', 'amount', 'size', 'price']
['apple', '1 dozen', '3', '8']
['cherry', '84', '100 g', '3.5']
['orange', '1 dozen', '3', '9']
```

Desired output:

```
['item', 'amount', 'size', 'price']
['apple', '12', '3', '8']
['cherry', '84', '100 g', '3.5']
['orange', '12', '3', '9']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input is in the file `amounts.csv`, you can try the following:

```
import csv

# Keep a dictionary of the changes you want to make
changes = {
    '1 dozen': 12
    }

with open('amounts.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    # Iterating through the list of lists
    for row in reader:
        # Look up each value in your dictionary and return the
        # corresponding 'changes' value if it finds a match.
        # If a match isn't found, just return the item itself.
        print [changes.get(item, item) for item in row]
```

Which would output:

```
['item', 'amount', 'size', 'price']
['apple', 12, '3', '8']
['cherry', '84', '100 g', '3.5']
['orange', 12, '3', '9']
```

`print` here was just to show the output - you could adjust to suit whatever your use case is.

Comment: Thanks! I thought the answer would work when manipulating a csv file. import csv
l = open('amount.csv', 'rb')
any suggestions with this variation?

Comment: @Sean Sure, I just added an edit - let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: It does, I need to read more about lists, running into the issue of each letter being an object in the list:['i', 't', 'e', 'm', ',', 'a', 'm', 'o', 'u', 'n', 't', ',', 's', 'i', 'z', 'e', ',', 'p', 'r', 'i', 'c', 'e', '\r', '\n']
['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', ',', '1', ' ', 'd', 'o', 'z', 'e', 'n', ',', '3', ',', '8', '\r', '\n']
['c', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'r', 'y', ',', '8', '4', ',', '1', '0', '0', ' ', 'g', ',', '3', '.', '5']

Comment: @Sean Can you post the code you are using right now? Happy to help debug (and in general, feel free to post your code anytime you post here - makes it easier for people to spot any tricky bugs).

Comment: @Sean No prob :) (Assuming it was iterating through the `reader` object instead of the `row` - I've done that a number of times before). Good luck with everything.